# Adding ACF Relationship field to Custom User Registration form

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom registration form for my WordPress website, because I didn't want to use the default one and I wanted to add more fields.

I am using ACF where I created a relationship field group called 'related_study_paths' that is filtered using a custom post type called 'studypath'. I have set the location of the field group to "Show this field group if User Form is equal to Register". But since I am not using the default WordPress register form, where it does show up, It, however, does not show up on my custom registration form. How do I make that happen?

I have tried the following code but the ACF fields do not show up. It's just a blank field. How do I fix this and save a related study path for a new user?

Custom Registration Form in functions.php:

```
<?PHP

// user registration login form
function mepoNET_registration_form() {
 
    // only show the registration form to non-logged-in members
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
 
        // check if registration is enabled
        $registration_enabled = get_option('users_can_register');
 
        // if enabled
        if($registration_enabled) {
            $output = mepoNET_registration_fields();
        } else {
            $output = __('User registration is not enabled');
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
add_shortcode('register_form', 'mepoNET_registration_form');

// registration form fields
function mepoNET_registration_fields() {
    
    ob_start(); ?>  
        <h3 class="mepoNET_reg_header"><?php _e('Register New Account'); ?></h3>
        
        <?php 
        // show any error messages after form submission
        mepoNET_register_messages(); ?>
        
        <form id="mepoNET_registration_form" class="mepoNET_reg_form" action="" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <p class="input_container">
                    <label for="mepoNET_user_username"><?php _e('Username'); ?></label>
                    <input name="mepoNET_user_username" id="mepoNET_user_username" class="reg_input_field" type="text"/>
                </p>
                <p class="input_container">
                    <label for="mepoNET_user_email"><?php _e('Email'); ?></label>
                    <input name="mepoNET_user_email" id="mepoNET_user_email" class="reg_input_field" type="email"/>
                </p>
                <p class="input_container">
                    <label for="mepoNET_user_first"><?php _e('First Name'); ?></label>
                    <input name="mepoNET_user_first" id="mepoNET_user_first" type="text" class="reg_input_field" />
                </p>
                <p class="input_container">
                    <label for="mepoNET_user_last"><?php _e('Last Name'); ?></label>
                    <input name="mepoNET_user_last" id="mepoNET_user_last" type="text" class="reg_input_field"/>
                </p>
                <p class="input_container"> 
                    <label for="password"><?php _e('Password'); ?></label>
                    <input name="mepoNET_user_pass" id="password" class="reg_input_field" type="password"/>
                </p>
                <p class="input_container">
                    <label for="password_again"><?php _e('Password Again'); ?></label>
                    <input name="mepoNET_user_pass_confirm" id="password_again" class="reg_input_field" type="password"/>
                </p>

                <p class="input_container">
                    <label for="mepoNET_user_bio"><?php _e('Biographical Description'); ?></label>
                    <textarea name="mepoNET_user_bio" id="mepoNET_user_bio" class="reg_input_field" oninput="commentResize(this)" rows="5" maxlength="80" style="resize: none; padding: 16px 20px; overflow: hidden;"></textarea>
                </p>

                <p class="input_container">
                    <label><?php _e('Select Role:'); ?></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="mepoNET_user_role[]" value="student"/> <?php _e('Student'); ?></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="mepoNET_user_role[]" value="faculty"/> <?php _e('Faculty'); ?></label>
                </p>

                <p class="input_container">
                    <label for="related_study_paths"><?php _e('Related Study Paths'); ?></label>
                    <?php
                    // Retrieve the current user's selected study paths
                    $selected_study_paths = get_field('related_study_paths', 'user_' . get_current_user_id());

                    // Render the ACF Relationship field choices
                    acf_form(array(
                        'post_id' => 'user_' . get_current_user_id(),
                        'post_title' => false,
                        'field_groups' => array('group_64c106c91a3dd'), // Replace with your field group key
                        'fields' => array('related_study_paths'), // Replace with your field name
                        'return' => false,
                        'submit_value' => false,
                        'values' => array('related_study_paths' => $selected_study_paths), // Pass the selected choices
                    ));

                    if ($selected_study_paths) {
                        echo '<ul>';
                        foreach ($selected_study_paths as $study_path) {
                            echo '<li>' . get_the_title($study_path) . '</li>';
                        }
                        echo '</ul>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </p>

                <p class="input_container">
                    <input type="hidden" name="mepoNET_csrf" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('mepoNET-csrf'); ?>"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Register Your Account'); ?>" class="reg_button"/>
                </p>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}



// register a new user
function mepoNET_add_new_user() {
    if (isset( $_POST["mepoNET_user_username"] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['mepoNET_csrf'], 'mepoNET-csrf')) {
      $user_login       = $_POST["mepoNET_user_username"];  
      $user_email       = $_POST["mepoNET_user_email"];
      $user_first       = $_POST["mepoNET_user_first"];
      $user_last        = $_POST["mepoNET_user_last"];
      $user_pass        = $_POST["mepoNET_user_pass"];
      $user_bio         = $_POST["mepoNET_user_bio"];
      $pass_confirm     = $_POST["mepoNET_user_pass_confirm"];
      $selected_roles   = isset($_POST['mepoNET_user_role']) ? $_POST['mepoNET_user_role'] : array();
      
      // this is required for username checks
      require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php');

    $allowed_roles = array('student', 'faculty'); // Define allowed roles
    $assigned_role = 'subscriber'; // Default role

    foreach ($selected_roles as $role) {
        if (in_array($role, $allowed_roles)) {
            $assigned_role = $role;
            break; // Assign the first valid role and exit the loop
        }
    }
      
      if(username_exists($user_login)) {
          // Username already registered
          mepoNET_errors()->add('username_unavailable', __('Username already taken'));
      }
      if(!validate_username($user_login)) {
          // invalid username
          mepoNET_errors()->add('username_invalid', __('Invalid username'));
      }
      if($user_login == '') {
          // empty username
          mepoNET_errors()->add('username_empty', __('Please enter a username'));
      }
      if(!is_email($user_email)) {
          //invalid email
          mepoNET_errors()->add('email_invalid', __('Invalid email'));
      }
      if(email_exists($user_email)) {
          //Email address already registered
          mepoNET_errors()->add('email_used', __('Email already registered'));
      }
      if($user_pass == '') {
          // passwords do not match
          mepoNET_errors()->add('password_empty', __('Please enter a password'));
      }
      if($user_pass != $pass_confirm) {
          // passwords do not match
          mepoNET_errors()->add('password_mismatch', __('Passwords do not match'));
      }
      
      $errors = mepoNET_errors()->get_error_messages();
      
      // if no errors then cretate user
      if(empty($errors)) {
          
          $new_user_id = wp_insert_user(array(
                  'user_login'          => $user_login,
                  'user_pass'           => $user_pass,
                  'user_email'          => $user_email,
                  'first_name'          => $user_first,
                  'last_name'           => $user_last,
                  'description'         => $user_bio,
                  'user_registered'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                  'role'                => $assigned_role,
              )
          );


          if($new_user_id) {
              // send an email to the admin
              wp_new_user_notification($new_user_id);
              
              // log the new user in
              wp_setcookie($user_login, $user_pass, true);
              wp_set_current_user($new_user_id, $user_login);   
              do_action('wp_login', $user_login);
              
              // send the newly created user to the home page after logging them in
              wp_redirect(home_url()); exit;

              $selected_study_paths = $_POST['acf']['related_study_paths']; // Retrieve the selected study paths
              update_field('related_study_paths', $selected_study_paths, 'user_' . $new_user_id);

            }            
        }
    }
}

add_action('init', 'mepoNET_add_new_user');

// used for tracking error messages
function mepoNET_errors(){
    static $wp_error; // global variable handle
    return isset($wp_error) ? $wp_error : ($wp_error = new WP_Error(null, null, null));
}

// displays error messages from form submissions
function mepoNET_register_messages() {
    if($codes = mepoNET_errors()->get_error_codes()) {
        echo '<div class="mepoNET_errors">';
            // Loop error codes and display errors
           foreach($codes as $code){
                $message = mepoNET_errors()->get_error_message($code);
                echo '<span class="error"><strong>' . __('Error') . '</strong>: ' . $message . '</span><br/>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }   
}
```

Custom Page Template:

```
<div class="hidden-header">
    <?php acf_form_head(); ?>
    <?php get_header();?>
</div>

<div class="register-container">
    <div class="entry-logo">
            <h1><a href="#"><span>MEPO</span>.NETWORK</a></h1>
        </div>
    <div class="register-box">
        <?php
        echo do_shortcode('[register_form]'); ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Registration Form mepoNET_registration_fields() function):**

```
<p class="input_container">
    <label for="mepoNET_user_study_path"><?php _e('Related Study Path'); ?></label>
    <select name="mepoNET_user_study_path" id="mepoNET_user_study_path" class="mepoNET_user_study_path">
        <option value="">Select Study Path</option>
        <?php
        // Retrieve options from the 'studypath' custom post type
        $study_paths = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'studypath',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        ));

        foreach ($study_paths as $study_path) {
            echo '<option value="' . $study_path->ID . '">' . $study_path->post_title . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

This code generates a dropdown select element populated with study path options retrieved from the 'studypath' custom post type.

**User Registration Handler (mepoNET_add_new_user() function):**

```
$selected_study_path = isset($_POST['mepoNET_user_study_path']) ? $_POST['mepoNET_user_study_path'] : '';
if (!empty($selected_study_path)) {
    update_field('related_study_paths', array($selected_study_path), 'user_' . $new_user_id);
}
```

Here, the selected study path is captured from the form data. If a study path is selected, the update_field() function from the Advanced Custom Fields plugin is used to update the 'related_study_paths' field of the user's meta data.

**User Registration Action (add_action('user_register','mepoNET_update_user_study_paths')):**

```
function mepoNET_update_user_study_paths($user_id) {
    $selected_study_path = isset($_POST['mepoNET_user_study_path']) ? $_POST['mepoNET_user_study_path'] : '';
    if (!empty($selected_study_path)) {
        update_field('related_study_paths', array($selected_study_path), 'user_' . $user_id);
    }
}
add_action('user_register', 'mepoNET_update_user_study_paths');
```

This function is hooked to the user_register action, which is triggered when a new user is registered. It captures the selected study path from the form data and updates the 'related_study_paths' field for the newly registered user.